# How can i use define preprocessor to define function-pointer?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to create a preprocessor for function-pointer *creatingI() but i can't do that. What is wrong?

```
#define  *creatingI() *CreatInt();
```

Error:

```
error C2007: #define syntax
```

Comment: Why on Earth do you wish to do this?

Comment: @EdHeal, that is the task((

Comment: For one, `*creatingI` is not a valid identifier, so it cannot be used to name a macro. Furthermore, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That is not valid syntax. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Greetings to your teacher: he should take a beginner's course in C programming! Anyone doing that in a project I'm in will have a a very serious talk about his abilities with me. Sure you are not suppose to do a `typedef`?

Comment: Your requirement doesn't make any sense.  Are you creating a macro for a function pointer *type* or a function *name*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name following the directive `define` must be **identifier** so you need to write your function-like macro with a name starting with either {underscore,letter} and followed by {underscore,letter, digits}.

so just remove the wildcard `*`:

```
#define  creatingI() *CreatInt();
```

---

From C99 6.10:

> `# define identifier replacement-list new-line`

From C99 6.4.2 :

> Syntax
>
> **identifier:**
>
> identifier-nondigit
>
> identifier identifier-nondigit
>
> identifier digit
>
> **identifier-nondigit**:
>
> nondigit
>
> universal-character-name
>
> other implementation-defined characters
>
> **nondigit**:
>
> one of
>
> _ a b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m n o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z A B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M N O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W
> X  Y  Z
>
> **digit:**
>
> one of 0 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

Comment: Yep, now it is working,

Comment: C99 is not standard C. You should cite the **valid** version of the standard. And that is not a function pointer (or can define one).

Comment: @Olaf unless you claim this has changed in C11, saying "C99 is not standard C" is a ridiculous objection

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. Everyone, please refrain from posting off-topic comments, especially comments about other users.

Comment: @Olaf Just curious: Have you downvoted the answer for that reason ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス: Whoever downvoted might have noticed this macro cannot be used to declare a function pointer, but a _function returning a pointer_ (assumign there is a type specifier before the macro) (with a strongly deprecated non-prototype parameter-list.

Comment: @Olaf  macros is only used as replacement so I was answering the question based on the error. She could use it for multiplication which makes that definition significant. OP was not clear enough on the use of the macro !

Comment: That's the point: The question is too unclear to be seriously answered. I'm not sure OP really understands the original problem. So it would have been better to wait for clarification as requested by the comments before providing a missleading answer. The replacement text is not practically useful (that's not your fault), unless you want to write obfuscated code (but then you don't use such names). All this renders your answer "not helpful". (OP thinking it is in fact makes it even more suspectible he understands the problem).

Comment: Then how do you explain his first comment on my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Macro name in a #define instruction must be an identifier i.e it must start with either an alphabet or _ with rest of the characters being a number,alphabet or _.
It cannot start with *